# Run a .exe file when a file is opened in a folder

Tags: c, windows, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I am mounting a folder as a virtual drive and i want to run a .exe file everytime user opens any file present in that folder. To be precise the folder would contain dummy files present on some other machine. By dummy files i mean the file would be listed but it would be a empty file. Whenever user opens a file i want the .exe program to download that file from another machine and display it to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That functionality (remote access on demand) can be implemented using [reparse points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [file system filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/).

Answer (score 0):

You could
    use `hooks` to rewrite the jump address of `OpenFile` and in the
    detour function check for the handle type, retrieve it's info by
    using `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, parse the data, download
    what you need, open the downloaded file and then return
    `STATUS_SUCCESS` or any appropriate error status in case one occurs.

**Note**

- this is a bit more complicated as you also need a `auto-inject`
  mechanism to inject function/library into each process according to
  it's architecture.
- this is not a safe procedure as most AV's will most likely consider your code malware.

Comment: I could try this but since i am still new to programming could you please elaborate on how to do things exactly?

Comment: Hooking SSDT is better to be avoided; such a program will rightfully be recognized as malware. The right tool is reparse points, which was created for exactly this purpose. In any case, this task is not for beginners.

Comment: How to use reparse points to fulfil my need. Could you please elaborate

Comment: No, I can't, my experience with that is rather limited. I used reparse points but I never implemented any. And you will also need to write a file system filter. The hooking method may be preferable if your program is not intended to go public. However no matter what method you decide to use, this task **is not** for people who are new to programming.